# RESTORE HEADERONLY takes over 10 minutes to complete

Tags: sql-server-2016, restore

I have a database backup that has been taken on another server (That I don't have access to) I want to restore the `HEADERONLY` and when I do so:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM  DISK = N'D:\SqlServer\backups\MyDB.bak'
```

the operation takes around 12minutes to complete. When I look at `sp_whoisactive` , I can see the wait is `PARALLEL_BACKUP_QUEUE`

I can see that the backup was taken on a SQL Server SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU13 and the server restoring is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17)

The file has a single backup inside and is on the D:\ drive of the server where I am running the `RESTORE WITH HEADERONLY` command. The file is 16GB (the backup is compressed) The server is a test server and is effectively doing nothing so disk activity is low to nil.

This only happens for this backup file, others show the output within a second (files in the same location and of a larger file size)

I found that when I backup the database that was restored from `D:\SqlServer\backups\MyDB.bak` to a new file `D:\SqlServer\backups\MyDBnew.bak` I can run

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM  DISK = N'D:\SqlServer\backups\MyDBnew.bak'
```

and it runs instantly.

When I try to backup the database to the same file we used for the restore:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = N'D:\SqlServer\backups\MyDB.bak' WITH STATS =1, COMPRESSION, INIT
```

I get

> Msg 3268, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot use the backup file
> 'D:\SqlServer\backups\BuildBackups\MyDB.bak' because it was originally
> formatted with sector size 512 and is now on a device with sector size
> 4096.

Is the mismatched sector size of the disks on the source and destination the reason for the slow reading of the header?

Comment: @AaronBertrand of course, updated

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's a good idea, I'll do that tomorrow and see what happens (I assume you mean the restored database) Unfortunately the server the backup originates from is not one I have access to, though i will be getting a new backup of it daily, so I will see what happens with tomorrow's backup too

Comment: @AaronBertrand updated after some more testing....